# jQuery hashing and loading file, string formating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, hash, load

I'm loading content dynamically like this:

```
  $("#id a").click(function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     var hash = this.parentNode.hash;
        $("#show").load('files/'+ hash +'.html'); 
        $("#show").fadeIn(300);     
 });
```

But the hash is #first, #second, #third so I have to name files #first.html, #second.html etc. How to edit hash string and cut the # thing, so I'll be able to load files named first.html, second.html etc. without the hash (#) sign?

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Substr), [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), or [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

```
'files/' + hash.substring(1) + '.html'
```

or

```
hash.slice(1)
```

or

```
hash.substr(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#id a").click(function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     var hash = this.parentNode.hash;
        $("#show").load('files/'+ hash.replace('#','') +'.html'); 
        $("#show").fadeIn(300);     
 });
```